Shedding faces and decomposability in simplicial complexes
Definition:
A pure d-dimensional complex
$\Delta$ is $k$-decomposable if either $\Delta$ is a $d-$simplex or $\Delta$ contains a face $F$ such that

$\dim(F) \leq k$
both $\Delta \setminus F$ and  $\operatorname{Link}_\Delta F$ are $k$-decomposable, and
$\Delta \setminus F$ is pure (and the dimensions stays same as that $\Delta$).

A face $F$ which satisfies the third condition is called a shedding face of $\Delta$.

Question: Let $\Delta$ be a simplicial complex. Suppose $\Delta$ is $d$-decomposable for some $0 \leq d$, and $F$ is a shedding face of $\Delta$. If $\Delta \setminus F$ and $\operatorname{Link}_\Delta (F)$ are $0$-decomposable, can we conclude that $\Delta$ is $0$-decomposable?


Wouldn't a positive answer to your question imply that every shellable complex is vertex-decomposable (= 0-decomposable)?

@RussWoodroofe: Yes. I expect to prove that a shellable simplicial complex implies a vertex-decomposable simplicial complex given the provided hypothesis. Specifically, if F is a shedding face such that the deletion of F and the Link of F are shellable, then the simplicial complex is shellable. Similarly, I am pondering a similar question: if the deletion of F and the Link of F are vertex decomposable (where F is a shedding face and the simplicial complex is d-decomposable), can we conclude that the simplicial complex is vertex decomposable?

You may have already run across this, but Hachimori has a nice library of simplicial complexes which might be a good place to look for (or rule out) counterexamples.

@user177523, my point is that any shellable but not vertex-decomposable complex is a counterexample to the thing you expect to prove.  Take any last step where there is no shedding vertex.  Explicit example of shellable but not vertex-decomposable can be found in https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02837 .  (The example there is even flag.)

I'll also comment that there's little reason to require pure-ness here.  For vertex-decomposable, this goes back to Björner and Wachs.  The "pure deletion" condition in the general situation becomes a sensible exchange condition.  My favorite place to read about this is my paper :-) "Chordal and sequentially Cohen-Macaulay clutters"; you can also find it in Jonsson's "Optimal decision trees on simplicial complexes".
